# How to absolutely position SVG's behind an image in responsive manner with Tailwind?

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css, css-position

I am trying to position SVG's as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkQZL.png). The SVG's should remain in the positions when resizing the screen. Here is a [playground link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RXyJN2qMMt) before my attempt.

I tried to create a wrapper div with a negative z-index, but it causes the image to be lost when I apply the negative z-index (-z-10). See [playground with attempt](https://play.tailwindcss.com/wClpLx3lP7).

I would like to position 3 leafs similar to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a position parent container that encapsulates the image. Ensure that it has `position: relative; z-index: 0` such that it is a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context) for its children.

Position the leaf graphics as required, with `z-index: -10` so that they are behind the image. Since we created the stacking context on the parent element, they will still be visible on the page even with a negative `z-index`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="relative z-0 ml-32 mt-16 w-max">
  <img class="rounded-l-md rounded-r-3xl" src="https://placehold.co/308x392" width="308" height="392" />
  <svg viewBox="0 0 87 97" class="absolute -z-10 -rotate-45 w-20 -top-14 -left-14"><use href="#leaf" /></svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 87 97" class="absolute -z-10 -rotate-45 -scale-x-100 w-40 bottom-4 -left-32"><use href="#leaf" /></svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 87 97" class="absolute -z-10 rotate-45 w-36 bottom-32 -right-24"><use href="#leaf" /></svg>
</div>

<svg class="w-0 h-0" viewBox="0 0 87 97" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="leaf">
  <path d="M85.2 47C85.2 47 82.7 51.6 80.6 52.4C78.6 53.2 57.7 62.4 54.3 61.9C51 61.3 57.7 56.2 75.5 48.7C93.3 41.3 75.5 20.6 75.5 20.6L75.2 21.5C72.9 29.4 67.6 36.1 60.3 39.8C57.4 41.3 54.7 43.6 52.2 43C44.2 40.9 84.7 21.8 64.6 14.1C44.5 6.4 39.3 0.4 39.3 0.4C35.2 7.2 18.6 11.2 18.6 18.7C18.7 26.2 31.5 31.4 28.1 34.2C24.8 37.1 14.7 22.1 14.7 22.1C7.20003 28.6 6.70003 33.5 6.70003 33.5C10.1 47.9 31.2 57 21.7 56.2C7.40003 55 2.60003 43 2.60003 43C1.60003 47.4 0.600034 55.1 0.800034 62.3C1.10003 70.4 3.60003 78.2 8.20003 84.8C19.9 101.4 32.5 90.2 37.3 84.7V83C33 85.8 26.9 87.8 19.2 88.7C18.5 88.8 17.3 88.5 17.2 87.8C17.1 87.3 17.5 87 18.4 86.9C26.7 85.9 33 83.6 37.1 80.1C37.1 79.8 37.2 79.6 37.3 79.5C37.3 79.5 37.4 79.3 37.4 79.2V78.2C37.1 78.1 36.8 78 36.4 77.9C35.8 77.8 35.3 77.7 34.5 77.7C34.2 77.7 33.8 77.7 33.4 77.7C33 77.7 32.5 77.6 32.1 77.6H29.4C29 77.6 28.5 77.6 28.1 77.6C27.3 77.6 26.4 77.6 25.6 77.7C24.9 77.7 24.2 77.7 23.5 77.7C22.5 77.7 21.5 77.6 20.6 77.5C19.6 77.4 18.5 77.3 17.6 77.1L14.9 76.5C14.5 76.4 14.1 76.3 13.6 76.1C13.3 76 13.1 75.9 12.9 75.8C12.8 75.7 12.7 75.7 12.6 75.7H12C11.8 75.6 11.6 75.3 11.7 75.1C11.8 74.9 12.1 74.7 12.3 74.8L12.4 74.9C12.5 74.9 12.6 75 12.7 75C12.9 75 13.1 75.1 13.3 75.2C13.5 75.2 13.6 75.3 13.8 75.3L15 75.6C15.7 75.8 16.6 76 17.6 76.1C18.5 76.2 19.5 76.3 20.5 76.4C20.8 76.4 21.1 76.4 21.5 76.4C22.2 76.4 22.8 76.4 23.4 76.4C24.4 76.4 25.4 76.3 26.4 76.2C27.4 76.1 28.4 76 29.3 75.9C29.7 75.9 30.2 75.8 30.7 75.8C31.2 75.8 31.6 75.8 32 75.7C32.4 75.7 32.7 75.7 32.9 75.7C33.5 75.7 34 75.7 34.6 75.7C35.7 75.7 36.5 75.8 37.2 75.9L37.3 68.6C37.2 68.6 37.1 68.6 37 68.6C36.8 68.6 36.6 68.5 36.5 68.5C36.2 68.5 35.8 68.4 35.3 68.3C35 68.2 34.6 68.1 34.3 68C34 67.9 33.7 67.9 33.3 67.8C33 67.7 32.7 67.6 32.4 67.5C32 67.4 31.5 67.2 31 67.1L30.3 66.8C29.7 66.6 29 66.3 28.3 66C28 65.9 27.7 65.7 27.4 65.6C26.8 65.4 26.2 65.1 25.5 64.8C24.6 64.4 23.7 64 22.8 63.5C21 62.6 19.2 61.6 17.6 60.7C16.5 60.1 15.4 59.4 14.4 58.8C14 58.5 13.5 58.3 13.1 58C10.6 56.5 9.00003 55.4 9.00003 55.4C8.80003 55.2 8.70003 54.9 8.90003 54.7C9.10003 54.5 9.40003 54.4 9.60003 54.6C9.60003 54.6 11.3 55.7 13.9 57.2C14.3 57.4 14.7 57.6 15.1 57.9C16.1 58.4 17.2 59.1 18.4 59.6C20.1 60.5 21.9 61.3 23.7 62.1L26.4 63.3C27.3 63.7 28.2 64 29.1 64.3L29.8 64.5C30.4 64.7 31 64.9 31.6 65.1C32.4 65.3 33.2 65.5 33.9 65.7C34.5 65.9 35.1 66 35.6 66L36.2 66.1C36.6 66.2 37 66.2 37.3 66.2H37.4L37.6 52.4L37 52.3C36.6 52.2 36.2 52.1 35.8 51.9C35.3 51.7 34.7 51.5 34 51.3C33.6 51.2 33.2 51 32.8 50.8C32.5 50.7 32.3 50.5 32 50.4C31.6 50.2 31.2 50 30.8 49.7C30.5 49.5 30.2 49.3 29.8 49.2C29 48.7 28.2 48.2 27.5 47.8C26.8 47.3 26.1 46.8 25.3 46.2C24.9 45.9 24.6 45.6 24.2 45.3C23.8 45 23.5 44.7 23.1 44.4C22.8 44.1 22.4 43.8 22.1 43.5C21.8 43.2 21.5 42.9 21.2 42.7C21 42.5 20.8 42.3 20.6 42.1C20.2 41.7 19.8 41.4 19.5 40.9C19.3 40.7 19 40.4 18.8 40.1C18.6 39.8 18.3 39.6 18.1 39.3C16.4 37.3 15.4 35.9 15.3 35.8C15.1 35.6 15.2 35.3 15.4 35.1C15.6 34.9 15.9 35 16.1 35.2C16.1 35.2 17.2 36.6 19.1 38.5L20.6 40C20.8 40.2 21.1 40.4 21.3 40.6C21.6 40.9 22 41.2 22.3 41.5C22.9 42.1 23.6 42.6 24.3 43.1C25 43.6 25.7 44.1 26.4 44.7C27 45.1 27.8 45.6 28.5 46C28.8 46.2 29.2 46.4 29.5 46.6C29.9 46.8 30.3 47.1 30.6 47.2C30.9 47.3 31.2 47.5 31.5 47.6C31.9 47.8 32.3 48 32.7 48.1L33.2 48.3C33.7 48.5 34.2 48.7 34.7 48.9C35.3 49.1 35.9 49.3 36.4 49.4C36.8 49.5 37.3 49.6 37.6 49.7L38 28.3C37.9 28.2 37.9 28.2 37.8 28.1C37.7 28 37.6 28 37.5 27.9C37.4 27.8 37.4 27.8 37.3 27.7L37.2 27.6C37 27.4 36.8 27.2 36.6 27.1C36.3 26.9 36.2 26.7 36 26.5C35.9 26.4 35.8 26.3 35.7 26.2C35.4 25.9 35.2 25.7 35 25.4L34.8 25.2C34.5 24.9 34.3 24.5 34.1 24C33.9 23.6 33.7 23.3 33.5 23L33.4 22.9C33 22.1 32.6 21.3 32.3 20.5C32.2 20.2 32.1 19.9 32 19.6C31.8 19.2 31.7 18.7 31.5 18.4C31 17.2 30.9 16.2 30.9 16.2C30.9 15.9 31 15.7 31.3 15.7C31.5 15.6 31.8 15.8 31.9 16C31.9 16 32.2 16.8 32.7 18C32.8 18.2 32.9 18.4 33 18.6C33.2 19 33.4 19.5 33.7 20C34.1 20.7 34.5 21.4 35 22.1C35.2 22.3 35.3 22.4 35.4 22.6C35.5 22.8 35.6 22.9 35.7 23C35.9 23.2 36 23.3 36.1 23.5C36.2 23.6 36.3 23.8 36.5 23.9C36.6 24 36.7 24.1 36.8 24.2C36.9 24.4 37.1 24.5 37.2 24.6C37.4 24.7 37.5 24.9 37.7 25C37.8 25.1 37.9 25.2 38 25.3C38.1 25.4 38.1 25.4 38.2 25.4L38.4 6.1C38.4 5.8 38.6 5.6 38.9 5.6C39.2 5.6 39.4 5.8 39.4 6.1L39.7 39C39.8 38.9 39.9 38.9 40.1 38.8C40.4 38.7 40.6 38.6 40.9 38.4C41.4 38.2 42 37.9 42.6 37.6C42.8 37.5 43 37.4 43.2 37.3C43.6 37.1 44.1 36.9 44.6 36.6C45.3 36.2 46 35.8 46.7 35.3C47.4 34.8 48.1 34.3 48.9 33.8C49.5 33.2 50.3 32.6 51 32.1C51.6 31.6 52.3 31 52.9 30.3C53.1 30 53.4 29.7 53.7 29.5C54.1 29.1 54.4 28.8 54.7 28.4C55.3 27.7 55.8 27.1 56.2 26.4C56.6 25.9 57 25.3 57.4 24.5C57.5 24.2 57.7 24 57.8 23.7C58 23.4 58.2 23.1 58.3 22.8C58.6 22.2 58.8 21.7 58.9 21.5C59.3 20.7 59.4 20.3 59.4 20.3C59.5 20 59.7 19.9 60 19.9C60.3 20 60.4 20.2 60.4 20.4C60.4 20.4 60.3 21 60 21.7C59.9 21.9 59.9 22 59.8 22.2C59.7 22.5 59.6 22.8 59.4 23.2C59.2 23.7 58.9 24.3 58.6 24.9C58.3 25.5 57.9 26.2 57.5 26.9C57.1 27.6 56.6 28.3 56.1 29C55.6 29.7 55 30.4 54.4 31.1C53.8 31.9 53 32.6 52.4 33.2C52 33.5 51.7 33.8 51.3 34.2C50.9 34.5 50.6 34.9 50.2 35.2C49.6 35.7 49.1 36.1 48.5 36.6L47.8 37C47.1 37.5 46.4 38 45.6 38.4C44.9 38.8 44.2 39.2 43.6 39.6C42.9 40.1 42.2 40.4 41.8 40.5C41.6 40.6 41.3 40.8 41.1 40.9C40.9 41 40.7 41.1 40.6 41.2C40.2 41.4 39.9 41.6 39.6 41.7L39.8 58.5C39.9 58.5 40.1 58.5 40.2 58.4C40.3 58.4 40.5 58.3 40.7 58.3C40.8 58.3 41 58.3 41.1 58.2C41.4 58.1 41.8 58 42.2 57.9C42.9 57.6 43.8 57.3 44.7 57C45 56.9 45.4 56.7 45.8 56.6C46.4 56.3 47.1 56.1 47.7 55.8C48.3 55.5 48.8 55.3 49.4 55C50 54.7 50.5 54.4 51.1 54.2C51.4 54 51.7 53.8 52.1 53.6C52.9 53.2 53.7 52.7 54.6 52.3C55 52.1 55.4 51.8 55.9 51.5C56.6 51.1 57.3 50.6 58.1 50.1C58.6 49.7 59.2 49.3 59.8 48.9C60.4 48.5 60.9 48.2 61.5 47.8C62.6 47 63.7 46.2 64.7 45.4C65.7 44.6 66.7 43.8 67.6 43.1C68.3 42.6 69 42 69.6 41.4L70.1 41C73.1 38.2 75 36.2 75.1 36.1C75.3 35.9 75.6 35.9 75.8 36.1C76 36.3 76 36.6 75.9 36.8C75.9 36.8 74 38.8 71 41.7C70.7 42 70.4 42.2 70.2 42.5C69.7 43 69.1 43.5 68.5 44C67.6 44.8 66.7 45.6 65.7 46.4C65.3 46.7 65 47 64.6 47.3C63.9 47.8 63.3 48.4 62.5 48.9C62 49.3 61.4 49.7 60.8 50.2C60.3 50.6 59.7 51 59.2 51.4C58.2 52.1 57 52.9 55.8 53.7C54.6 54.4 53.5 55.1 52.4 55.8C52 56 51.6 56.2 51.3 56.4C50.6 56.8 49.8 57.3 49.1 57.6C48.8 57.8 48.4 57.9 48.1 58.1C47.4 58.4 46.7 58.8 46 59C45.3 59.3 44.7 59.5 44.2 59.7C43.9 59.8 43.6 59.9 43.3 60C43 60.2 42.7 60.3 42.4 60.3L42 60.5C41.6 60.6 41.3 60.7 41 60.8C40.6 60.9 40.2 61 40 61.1L40.1 72.8L40.5 72.7C41.1 72.6 41.8 72.5 42.7 72.4C43.5 72.3 44.5 72.1 45.4 71.9L46.1 71.8C46.9 71.6 47.8 71.5 48.8 71.2C49.5 71 50.4 70.8 51.2 70.6L52.4 70.3C53.2 70.1 54 69.9 54.8 69.6C55.3 69.4 55.7 69.3 56.2 69.1C57.5 68.7 58.8 68.2 60.1 67.7C60.7 67.5 61.4 67.2 62 66.9C62.6 66.6 63.3 66.3 63.9 66.1L67.5 64.3C68.5 63.7 69.7 63.1 70.6 62.4C71.1 62.1 71.5 61.8 71.9 61.5C72.4 61.1 72.9 60.8 73.4 60.5C74.2 59.9 75 59.3 75.7 58.8C76.1 58.5 76.5 58.2 76.8 57.9C77 57.7 77.2 57.6 77.4 57.4C77.6 57.2 77.9 57.3 78.1 57.5C78.3 57.7 78.3 58 78.1 58.2L78 58.3C77.8 58.5 77.6 58.7 77.3 58.9C77 59.2 76.7 59.5 76.4 59.8C76 60.2 75.6 60.5 75.2 60.8C74.9 61.1 74.5 61.3 74.2 61.6L73.8 62C73 62.6 72.2 63.2 71.2 63.8C70.6 64.2 70 64.6 69.3 65C68.9 65.3 68.5 65.5 68 65.8C66.9 66.5 65.7 67.1 64.5 67.7C63.1 68.4 61.8 69 60.6 69.4C60.2 69.6 59.7 69.7 59.3 69.9C58.4 70.3 57.5 70.6 56.7 70.9C55.9 71.1 55.1 71.4 54.4 71.7C53.9 71.9 53.4 72 52.9 72.2C52.4 72.3 52 72.5 51.5 72.6C50.7 72.8 50 73 49.3 73.3L48.3 73.5C47.4 73.7 46.6 73.9 45.9 74.1C45 74.4 44 74.6 43.1 74.7C42.5 74.8 41.9 74.9 41.4 75L41 75.1C40.7 75.1 40.5 75.2 40.2 75.2V78.8H40.4C41.6 78.9 43.2 79.1 45 79.4C46.5 79.6 48.3 79.8 50.1 80L51.6 80.2C52.2 80.2 52.7 80.3 53.3 80.4C53.9 80.5 54.6 80.6 55.3 80.6C56 80.7 56.7 80.7 57.4 80.8C58 80.9 58.6 80.9 59.1 81C60.4 81.1 61.7 81.2 62.9 81.2H64.8C65.4 81.2 66 81.2 66.5 81.1C66.9 81.1 67.2 81.1 67.4 81C67.7 81 68 80.9 68.3 80.9C68.8 80.9 69.2 80.8 69.7 80.7H69.9C71 80.6 72 80.4 73 80.2C73.5 80.1 73.9 80 74.2 79.8H74.3C74.5 79.8 74.7 79.7 74.8 79.6C75 79.5 75.2 79.4 75.4 79.4C76.1 79.1 76.7 78.8 77.1 78.6L77.5 78.3C77.8 78.1 78 78 78.1 77.9C78.3 77.7 78.6 77.7 78.8 77.9C78.9 78 78.9 78.1 78.9 78.3C78.9 78.5 78.9 78.6 78.8 78.7C78.6 78.9 78.2 79.2 77.7 79.5C77.4 79.7 77.1 79.9 76.7 80C76.4 80.1 76.1 80.3 75.8 80.5C75.6 80.6 75.3 80.7 75.1 80.8C74.9 80.9 74.7 80.9 74.5 81C74.1 81.2 73.7 81.3 73.3 81.4H73.1C72.2 81.7 71.1 81.9 70 82.1C69.5 82.2 69 82.3 68.4 82.4H68.3C67.7 82.5 67.1 82.6 66.4 82.6C66.2 82.6 65.8 82.7 65.5 82.7C65.2 82.7 64.9 82.7 64.6 82.8C64.2 82.8 63.9 82.8 63.6 82.9C63.3 82.9 62.9 83 62.6 83C61.7 83.1 60.9 83 60 83C59.6 83 59.1 83 58.7 83C57.4 83 56.1 82.9 54.8 82.8H54.5C53.3 82.7 52.2 82.6 51.1 82.6C49.1 82.4 47.2 82.3 45.5 82.3L44.5 82.2C43.7 82.2 42.9 82.1 42.2 82C41.9 82 41.6 82 41.3 81.9C41.6 82.2 41.9 82.6 42.2 83C42.2 83 42.3 83.1 42.4 83.2C42.5 83.3 42.7 83.5 42.8 83.6C43 83.7 43.1 83.9 43.3 84C43.4 84.1 43.5 84.2 43.6 84.3C44.2 84.8 44.8 85.3 45.5 85.7C46.2 86.2 46.8 86.6 47.7 87C48.5 87.4 49.3 87.8 50.1 88.1C53 89.2 56.5 90 59.6 90.3C62.3 90.6 64 90.6 64.1 90.6C64.4 90.6 64.6 90.8 64.6 91.1C64.6 91.4 64.4 91.6 64.2 91.6C64.1 91.6 62.3 91.8 59.6 91.7C58 91.6 53.8 91.3 49.7 89.9C48.9 89.6 48 89.3 47.1 88.9L44.7 87.7C44 87.3 43.2 86.8 42.5 86.3C42.3 86.2 42.2 86.1 42 85.9C41.9 85.8 41.7 85.7 41.6 85.6C41.3 85.4 40.9 85 40.7 84.8C40.5 84.6 40.3 84.4 40.2 84.3V84.4C43.1 91.8 47.1 101.9 69.5 93.5C94.2 84.2 85.2 47 85.2 47Z" fill="#3B613E" />
</svg>
```